# IXMLDocument unable to read data because IXMLNode.Text property always empty

Tags: xml, delphi, xsd

I'm trying to read XML file with Delphi TXMLDocument parser but I'm unable to reach data in the nodes and I'm not able to figure out why this is happening. The XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<types:NotificaScarto xmlns:types="http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/sdi/messaggi/v1.0" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" versione="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/sdi/messaggi/v1.0 MessaggiTypes_v1.0.xsd ">
  <IdentificativoSdI>111</IdentificativoSdI>
  <NomeFile>IT01234567890_11111.xml.p7m</NomeFile>
  <DataOraRicezione>2013-06-06T12:00:00Z</DataOraRicezione>
  <RiferimentoArchivio>
    <IdentificativoSdI>100</IdentificativoSdI>
    <NomeFile>IT01234567890_11111.zip</NomeFile>
  </RiferimentoArchivio>
  <ListaErrori>
    <Errore>
      <Codice>00100</Codice>
      <Descrizione>Certificato di firma scaduto</Descrizione>
    </Errore>
  </ListaErrori>
  <MessageId>123456</MessageId>
  <Note>Note</Note>
</types:NotificaScarto>
```

I need to read the "DataOraRicezione" node so I'm using this code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  XMLD : IXMLDocument;
  N0,N1 : IXMLNode;
begin
  XMLD:=TXMLDocument.Create(Application);
  XMLD.LoadFromFile('d:\IT01131820936_00175_NS_001.xml');  // the XML is on a file
  XMLD.Active:=TRUE;
  N0:=XMLD.ChildNodes['types:NotificaScarto'];
  N1:=N0.ChildNodes['DataOraRicezione'];
  ShowMessage(N1.Text);  // Empty ?????
end;
```

I suppose that the problem could be related to the schema. I never read till now xml files like these I'm a newbie about it so I'm not capable to read that value. I search for similar answers but I couldn't reach my goal. Am I missing something?

Thank you
Davide

Comment: Not sure if it helps but testing your code and data I have seen two things: a) the `XSD` is not accessible from my place. Not sure if you need some kind of permission. b) The problem disappears if you remove all header attributes and the `types` prefix, i.e. you leave the root node as `NotificaScarto`.

Comment: I just saw that removing the header attributes then all works fine but it is not an acceptable solution in my context. Now I'll investigate on xsd accessibility. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to read the node value you must use the `FindNode` method.

```
function FindNode(NodeName, NamespaceURI: DOMString): IXMLNode; overload;
```

Like so

```
  N0:=XMLD.ChildNodes['types:NotificaScarto'];
  N1:=N0.ChildNodes.FindNode('DataOraRicezione', '');
  ShowMessage(N1.Text);
```

The `NamespaceURI` must be blank for this particular case because the namespace is not included in the node itself.

This will return

> 2013-06-06T12:00:00Z

Comment: +1, that works. The second parameter in `FindNode` was what I was missing in my tests. I had exactly the same code except for that parameter. :-)

Comment: +1, that works also for me! I don't understand well the reason but it works. Thanks!